# Java collections over arangoDB

Tags: java, arangodb

I am relatively new to ArangoDB. Is there any library written which implements java collections over ArangoDB. 
i.e creates an Arangodb server that stores the value in the database and extracts the values as and when needed. I am looking for something similar to Redisson (https://github.com/mrniko/redisson) which is implemented over Redis.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It should be possible to modify Redisson using the Java driver https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver for ArangoDB for the base communication. But this would require some work.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it is not possible at the moment. But if you want to you can modify the ArangoDB Java Driver (github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver). 
Everyone can contribute to the project and if you need any help with the work just ask the ArangoDB Team.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that Redis is an in-memory (but persistent-on-disk) database. This makes for screaming fast read/write operations, but at a high memory cost. ArangoDB, on the other hand, compromises some speed to limit the memory footprint, and does so quite well.

However, because of this difference, it does not necessarily make sense to do for ArangoDB what Redisson does for Redis - that is, expose its own Java Collection implementations which allow more direct interaction with the in-memory entities. You would most likely run into unwanted memory issues. Since memory optimization is an important (and nice!) feature of ArangoDB, I would avoid going down this path.

That being said, there are newer Java libraries available to help you easily integrate with ArangoDB.

- [JNoSQL](http://www.jnosql.org/) is a solid "JPA or ORM-like" framework written specifically for NoSQL databases. ArangoDB is one of many that is supported. It exposes convenient annotations and easily supports classic DAO/Repository patterns. There are [some good code examples](http://[JNoSQL][1]%20is%20a%20solid%20%22JPA%20or%20ORM-like%22%20framework%20written%20specifically%20for%20NoSQL%20databases.%20ArangoDB%20is%20one%20of%20many%20that%20is%20supported.) that'll help point you in the right direction.